# 3 cowboys duel - modified

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Three Cowboys have a shoot out. A shoots with 1/3 accuracy, B 1/2, C one (never misses). A goes first. The cowboys attempt to shoot the cowboy with the best shooting ability. What’s the probability that A is still alive?

Edit: We assume that after A, B goes first and then C

My approach:

Since it is given that they attempt to shoot the cowboy with the best shooting ability, both A & B would go for C.

1st case: C is knocked out and A & B remain in a duel

P(A win vs B) = 0.3 + (0.7 * 0.5 * 0.3) + (0.7 * 0.5 * 0.7 * 0.5 * 0.3) + .... infinite geometric progression

Thus P(A win vs B) = 0.3/(1 - 0.35) = 0.46

2nd case: C shoots B (after both A & B miss against C) and A & C remain in a duel

P(A win vs C) = 0.3

Now 1st case happens with Probability 2/3 (1/3 chance both A & B miss C)

2nd case happens with Probability 1/3

Thus P(A wins) = (2/3 * 0.46) + (1/3 * 1/3) = 0.42

Does the logic sound right or I have calculated it incorrectly?

Comment: What about A missing C and B killing C?

Comment: @Aadi I believe thats covered in the 1st case where either A or B kill C.

Comment: In the second case, either only A dies or both die, so a cannot win against C. B also cannot survive the first round

Comment: @KaiL1ng wouldn't A have a 0.3 chance of shooting C in the 2nd case as he goes 1st after C shoots B and thus wins? And yes, I agree that B cannot survive the 1st round.

Comment: @quantrader23 First of all: $\frac{1}{3} \color{red}{\neq} 0.3$. Or from where you have got the number $0.3$?

Comment: @callculus42 my bad genuine mistake. Does the logic seem ok tho?

Comment: @quantrader23 Make an edit. Otherwise it is too hard to comprehend your calculation.

Comment: @quantrader23 Why can A and B shoot several times on each other without any shoot of C?

Comment: @quantrader23 in the 2nd case, A and C are the only one's remaining. There is a 1/3 chance of A shooting C, but C will shoot A for sure, hence A cannot survive

Comment: @quantrader23: Could you explain the rules of 3-cowboy duel? I'm not a cowboy and don't understand who fires at whom and in which order.

Comment: @Aadi:Pl clarify the order in which people shoot, then I'll rework answer

Comment: @trueblueanil The order in which they shoot is A, B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

**Reworked after order of shooting given**

Case 1: $\;A \xcancel{C} \Longrightarrow BA\;$duel

Either B wins on first try with Pr = 1/2, or both B and A miss and they are back to square $1$

So if $b$ is the probability that B **ultimately** wins from **here**,

$b = \frac12 + (\frac12\frac23)b = \frac12 + \frac13\cdot b$

$\frac23 b = \frac12 \Longrightarrow b = \frac34\;\; a = \frac14$

Thus P(A wins) $= \frac13\frac14 = \frac1{12}$

Case 2: $AC\;B\xcancel{C}$ now $AB$ duel

Let $a$ be the uultimate probability that A wins, then, parallel to case 1, $a = \frac13 +(\frac23\frac12)a, \frac23\cdot a = \frac13 \Longrightarrow a = \frac12$

and P(A wins) $=\frac23\frac12\frac12 =\frac1{6}$

Case 3: $AC\; BC\xcancel{B}$ now an AC duel with A having only one chance

P(A wins) $= \frac23\frac12\cdot1 \cdot\frac13 =\frac19$

Adding up all cases, P(A wins) $= \frac1{12}+\frac1{6}+\frac19 = \frac{13}{36}\approx 0.3611$

Comment: In the 1st case if A misses the shot , there is still a 1/2 chance that B kills C. If however, B misses, then C would definitely kill B.

Comment: @quantrader23 , you need to mention if A,B and C go in a fixed order or not, your question is currently incomplete

Comment: By the way the second case is wrong @trueblueanil , I'm fairly certain that the duel goes chance by chance, A cannot get two chances in row as well. So the probability of B killing A is 3/4 and not 3/5 . I hope you understand that you are applying different rules in both the cases, if the concept of  relative probabilities are used , then A would have 1/3 divided by 4/3 i.e 1/4 chance and not 1/3 chance to kill C in the first case

Comment: @Aadi: Ok, I have  reworked the answer, sorry for typos on the way !

Comment: For the final calculation in the 2nd case, shouldnt it be 2/3 * 1/2 * 1/2 instead of 1/3 * 1/2 * 1/2. Since P(A missing C) is 2/3 thus giving 2nd case =1/6 instead of 1/12 and final Ans being 13/36 which matches @Aadi 's answer

Comment: Yea, well spotted typo

Answer (score 1):

If the question states that A, B and C go in that particular order. Lets draw out all the cases:

*' $\times$' means kill and '-' means miss.*

- $(A \times C) $ $(B - A)$  $(A - B)$ ..... $(A \times B)$
- $(A - C)$  $(B \times C)$  $(A - B)$ ..... $(A \times B)$
- $(A - C)$  $(B - C)$  $(C \times B)$ $(A \times C)$

For your solution you have calculated the third case accurately but you've somehow group the first and second into one. Hopefully you will be able to calculate from here onwards.

The final answer according to me is $\boxed{\frac{13}{36}}$ which is  $\boxed{0.36}$

Comment: PLease clarify the order in which they shoot, then I'll rework answer

Comment: A,B and C is the order in which they shoot.

Comment: This answer sounds right. Thanks for pointing out, I grouped the 1st 2 cases into 1.